# Java exception handling finally block

Tags: oop, exception

I just learned the lesson of Java `Exception Handling`. And I learned Java `finally` block is always executed whether exception is handled or not.

```
finally block
```

Is there any case when finally will not be executed?

Answer (score 1):

`finally block` will not be executed if program exits; either by calling `System.exit()` or by causing a fatal error that causes the process to abort.

More information - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 0):

The finally block is always called, except maybe if you do a System.exit().

Comment: This is a duplicate question and there are so many good answers in those original post. So you can vote for close question as duplicate. OP get more benefit from that.